# C# datagridview binding source with image path if not existing

Tags: c#, datagridview

Hello i have one question, im getting data to datagridview with bindingSource, my code is bellow;

```
string query= "SELECT a.id as id1,a.id2, a.system_id, CONCAT(b.path,a.image) as photo ,b.id as id5,b.name,b.path  FROM users a INNER JOIN systems b ON a.system_id=b.id  order by a.id DESC LIMIT 20";
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                var dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                bindingSource1.DataSource = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(p => new aclass() { id = (p["id1"].ToString()),  Photo= Image.FromFile(p["photo enter code here"].ToString()) }).ToList();
                conn.Close();


            }
```

This function getting image path and adding to list and showing in datagridview with photo, but my problem is if this photo is deleted not getting showing error,how to make if this photo is deleted adding one photo avatar default. If exist photo showing original photo. Thnks

Comment: You are going to have to provide a default path in the database query. Your SQL is going to look something like SELECT CASE WHEN myPath IS NULL THEN  '\\path\to\default\image' ELSE myPath END here's a link to the CASE WHEN syntax if your talking to a SQL Server db https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql

Comment: c# and winForm ? or ASP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if the file exists first and then either load it from the path or from the avatar path.

```
string avaterPath=@"D:\Images\NoImage.png";
string query= "SELECT a.id as id1,a.id2, a.system_id, CONCAT(b.path,a.image) as photo ,b.id as id5,b.name,b.path  FROM users a INNER JOIN systems b ON a.system_id=b.id  order by a.id DESC LIMIT 20";
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                var dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                bindingSource1.DataSource = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(p => new aclass() { id = (p["id1"].ToString()),  Photo=File.Exists(p["photo enter code here"].ToString())? Image.FromFile(p["photo enter code here"].ToString()):Image.FromFile(avaterPath) }).ToList();
                conn.Close();


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the file exists first and then either load it from the path or from the avatar path. You can use these helper functions:

```
private string LoadImage(string imagePath) {
  return Image.FromFile(MapImagePath(imagePath));
}

private string MapImagePath(string imagePath) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(imagePath))
    imagePath = GetNoImagePath();
  else {
    if (!File.Exists(imagePath))
      imagePath = GetNoImagePath();
  }
  return imagePath;
}

private string GetNoImagePath() {
  return "D:\ProjectFolder\Images\NoImage.png";
}
```

And now you can call them from your code like this:

```
var data = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(p => new aclass() {
  id = (p["id1"].ToString()),
  Photo = LoadImage(p["photo enter code here"].ToString())
}).ToList();
```

Note: Of course, you can make the path to the avatar a constant instead of a function. The function could be useful if you have several avatars and you want to return one of them based on some conditions.

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone, this is my solution;

```
 string avaterPath=@"D:\Images\NoImage.png";
string query= "SELECT a.id as id1,a.id2, a.system_id, CONCAT(b.path,a.image) as photo ,b.id as id5,b.name,b.path  FROM users a INNER JOIN systems b ON a.system_id=b.id  order by a.id DESC LIMIT 20";
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                var dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                bindingSource1.DataSource = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(p => new aclass() { id = (p["id1"].ToString()),  Photo=File.Exists(p["photo enter code here"].ToString())? Image.FromFile(p["photo enter code here"].ToString()):Image.FromFile(avaterPath) }).ToList();
                conn.Close();


            }
```